# Undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass - Erro ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loop

Eu tenho os seguintes códigos em Ruby em três arquivos diferentes. Segue eles:

**programa.rb**

```
require_relative "product"
require_relative "store"

cd = Product.new("CD",20.5)
pinico = Product.new("Pinico",30.6)

store = [cd,pinico]
test = Store.new(store)
puts test
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product
  attr_accessor :name, :price

  def initialize(name,price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end

  def to_s
    "name: #{@name} - price: #{@price}"
  end
end
```

**store.rb**

```
class Store
  attr_accessor :product, :total

  def initialize(product)
    @product = product
  end

  total = 0
  def to_s
    product.each do |product|
      puts product.price
      total += product.price
    end
    "Soma total dos produtos: #{@total}"
  end
end
```

A partir do arquivo store.rb, eu gostaria de somar o valor total dos produtos e retornar eles para o arquivo programa.rb, onde construo a classe. Quando eu rodo o mesmo arquivo no terminal, o mesmo me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
/home/cabox/workspace/test/store.rb:12:in `block in to_s': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /home/cabox/workspace/test/store.rb:10:in `each'
        from /home/cabox/workspace/test/store.rb:10:in `to_s'
        from programa.rb:9:in `puts'
        from programa.rb:9:in `puts'
        from programa.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Gostaria de saber como devo prosseguir para solucionar o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua classe **store.rb** a variável `total` é definida fora do método `def to_s`, logo ela fica inacessível para métodos de instância.

O código correto para ela seria o seguinte:

```
class Store
  attr_accessor :products

  def initialize(products)
    @products = products
  end

  def to_s
    total = 0
    products.each do |product|
      total += product.price
    end

    "Soma total dos produtos: #{total}"
  end
end
```

**Note** que eu

1. corrigi o nome da variável `@product` para `@products`,
2. removi a variável de instância `@total` e usei uma temporária dentro do escopo do `to_s`
3. retirei o `puts` que tinha dentro do `.each`.

Se vc usa Ruby > 2.4 quiser melhorar ainda mais seu código vc pode deixar o `def to_s` da seguinte forma:

```
def to_s
  "Soma total dos produtos: #{@products.sum(&:price)}"
end
```

Veja a documentação do método [Array#sum](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.4/array#method-i-sum). E o uso do `&:price` é [uma abreviação](http://devdocs.io/ruby~2.4/symbol#method-i-to_proc) quando o bloco é do tipo `@products.sum { |product| product.price }`.

Para versões < 2.4 vc pode usar `@products.map(&:price).reduce(&:+)`

Dá uma pesquisada rápida na internet sobre o escopo de variáveis em Ruby ([achei esse aqui](https://desenvolvimentoaberto.org/2014/12/28/ruby-classes-escopos-linux/)), ajuda muito quem está começando e é bem simples. Boa sorte :)

Comment: Exatamente isso que precisava! Sou novo em ruby e acabo tendo dúvidas sobre ele. O link que você me informou me ajudou muito a entender mais sobre isso. Muito Obrigado por toda a ajuda e atenção! :)